# how to reverse an event trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an EventTrigger Animation which change the Opacity of a TextBlock on click.
The use of this trigger is to hide my TextBlock when user click on it.
It works perfectly.

However, I can't figure out how can I reverse this EventTrigger - *Get opacity back* -.

When I try to change it in my code-behind, the trigger have the priority so it is not working.
I have thought about create a new EventTrigger which do the opposite nevertheless I don't know if I can call it in my code-behind..

My TextBlock is Hide = True only when user click on a button. This an error TextBlock.
The user can click on it to hide it.
If the user click again on the button, this TextBox is now hide by opacity.
I must change this opacity from the code-behind I do not see how figure out with an other method.

My XAML :

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ErrorTextBlock">
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.MouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ErrorTextBlock" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                     From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:2" 
                                     AutoReverse="False">
```

EDIT : I don't find the answer to my question however I find an other solution.
The problem was the order - Animation First, Code-Behind second -.
So I just write my XAML Animation the code behind.
The priority is now over and problem is solved. =)

Comment: What is supposed to trigger getting the opacity back?

Comment: In my code-behind : `ErrorTextBlock.Opacity = 1;`

Comment: I'm no expert, but you can't do everything in XAML. In case this is indeed not doable, what you need is a boolean to indicate if the error message has to be shown or not, and whenever you change this boolean (in your click event), start a storyboard in C# setting or unsetting the opacity (based on this boolean).

Comment: It might be a good alternative. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your desired behavior can be summed up as wanted to be able to adjust the `From` and `To` values in the animation according to the current state of the `TextBlock`.

I was able to accomplish this by writing a simple `IValueConverter` and binding the `TextBlock.Opacity` property to the animation's `To` property using the converter (and of course, the `Opacity` property to the `From` property without a converter).

The converter:

```
class SubtractFromConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double && parameter is double)
        {
            double doubleValue = (double)value, doubleParameter = (double)parameter;

            return doubleParameter - doubleValue;
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

My simple test XAML to demonstrate it:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock x:Name="textBox1" FontSize="36" Text="Hello world!">
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.MouseDown">
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="textBox1"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             From="{Binding ElementName=textBox1, Path=Opacity}"
                             Duration="0:0:2"
                             AutoReverse="False">
              <DoubleAnimation.To>
                <Binding ElementName="textBox1" Path="Opacity">
                  <Binding.Converter>
                    <local:SubtractFromConverter />
                  </Binding.Converter>
                  <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                    <system:Double>1.0</system:Double>
                  </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                </Binding>
              </DoubleAnimation.To>
            </DoubleAnimation>
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
  </TextBlock>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Opacity: " />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=textBox1, Path=Opacity}" />
  </StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Opacity: " />
    <TextBlock>
      <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding ElementName="textBox1" Path="Opacity">
          <Binding.Converter>
            <local:SubtractFromConverter />
          </Binding.Converter>
          <Binding.ConverterParameter>
            <system:Double>1.0</system:Double>
          </Binding.ConverterParameter>
        </Binding>
      </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
  </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Every time I click the `TextBlock`, it reverses the animation.

Note: some extra work on your part will be required to adapt the technique to ensure the animation always runs to the direction you want. For example, instead of just using the current `Opacity` value, bind to some other property that tracks the current toggle state.

But I hope that the basic technique – to use binding to dynamically control the `From` and `To` properties of the animation – is clear.